# ServiceStack.OrmLite 4.0.58 not creating proper SQL for boolean join conditions

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am attempting to join two tables using `ServiceStack.OrmLite` v4.0.58 but the SQL being generated for a boolean check is incorrect:

```
var exp = Db.From<AdjustmentRequest>()
             .Join<Account>()
             .LeftJoin<CardHolder>((ar, ch) => ch.IsPrimary == true && ar.AccountId == ch.AccountId)
```

is creating this (snippet) of SQL:

```
FROM "AdjustmentRequest" 
INNER JOIN "Account" 
ON ("Account"."Id" = "AdjustmentRequest"."AccountId") 
LEFT JOIN "CardHolder" 
ON ("CardHolder"."IsPrimary" AND ("AdjustmentRequest"."AccountId" = "CardHolder"."AccountId"))
```

You can see on the last line that the "IsPrimary" is not being compared to 1 (true).

This worked previously in 4.0.54.

Comment: What database are you connecting to? Eg, which OrmLite.SqlDialectProvider is your application setup with?

Comment: Dur, that's important, isn't it?  SqlServer2012 dialect

Comment: Can you provide all the classes used so I can try repro this?

Comment: I've provided a sample file this gist - https://gist.github.com/jklemmack/95722a1c5ae28f9179cdd141c271564b.  Note that there is inconsistent behavior in all 3 cases :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with a bool condition on a joined table in a JOIN expression should now be [fixed in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/935226c10007f767fb874bc153cf3e7d45aef538).

This change is available from v4.0.59 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Sweet.  Thanks Demis! 